# When I access SharePoint with my PC logged in as me, SharePoint automatically logs me in as Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer

I am logged into my domain with my user account but when I access the SharePoint site I am automatically logged in as "Administrator".

I can "Sign in as Different User". However when I change a file it still says last modified by "Administrator" and if I close the window and access SharePoint again I am back to being logged in as Administrator.

If I log into a different PC as me, SharePoint behaves normally. So it appears to be something on my local computer. I've tried deleting everything from IE's browsing history.

I guess it may have started when I logged out of SharePoint and back in as "Administrator" with the PC logged into my user account.

I would really appreciate any help, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it, I must have saved the password at some point and it was stored in my credentials in control panels.

Go to Start, Control Panel, User Accounts, then click Manage Your Network Passwords (Manage your credentials in W7), and look for the credentials you are referring to, if they are there remove them.